# Databricks: Jar file changed but does not reflect to cluster

Tags: apache-spark, jar, databricks, cluster-computing, jobs

I made a 'a' job with 'A' cluster and uploaded 'former.jar' file on dependent libraries.
I found that I had a typo on 'former.jar' so I changed it with 'latter.jar' file on the dependent libraries.
However, when I see the log I can see same error log with 'former.jar'

I tried to made a new job named 'b' with 'A' cluster but it does not reflect change of 'latter.jar' too. But when I made a new job named 'c' with 'B' cluster. it worked.
And then, I made a 'latterlatter.jar' and uploaded in 'c', it does not reflect too.

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Is it an all purpose cluster right? You need to reboot it after installing or deleting any library so the changes can take effect

Comment: yeah it was the problem thx.